# Folder Tree in array using PHP

Tags: php, iterator, directory

I am trying to display a folder tree. Its working all good. Below is the code.

```
$fileData = fillArrayWithFileNodes( new DirectoryIterator( $dir ) );

    function fillArrayWithFileNodes( DirectoryIterator $dir )
    {
      $data = array();
      foreach ( $dir as $node )
      {
        if ( $node->isDir() && !$node->isDot() )
        {
          $data[$node->getFilename()] = fillArrayWithFileNodes( new DirectoryIterator( $node->getPathname() ) );
        }
        else if ( $node->isFile() )
        {
          $data[] = $node->getFilename();
        }
      }
      return $data;
    }
```

But i have a new requirement. I want to have it in a class, so that i can use it this way.

```
    $tree = new folderTree();
    $structure = $tree->display('testdir',2); //2 is the level of subfolders
```

So i have wrapped everything in a class in the below way.

```
class folderTree {

    function display($dir,$level='') {
        $fileData = fillArrayWithFileNodes( new DirectoryIterator( $dir ) );

        function fillArrayWithFileNodes( DirectoryIterator $dir )
        {
          $data = array();
          foreach ( $dir as $node )
          {
            if ( $node->isDir() && !$node->isDot() )
            {
              $data[$node->getFilename()] = fillArrayWithFileNodes( new DirectoryIterator( $node->getPathname() ) );
            }
            else if ( $node->isFile() )
            {
              $data[] = $node->getFilename();
            }
          }
          return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

But i am really stuck in how to use the level.

**What is level ?**

```
-folder
    -childfolder (level1)
        file1
        file2
        -subchildfolder (level2)
            file1
            file2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the logic from below code:

```
<?php
function getFiles(RecursiveDirectoryIterator $rdi, $depth=0) {

    if (!is_object($rdi))
        return;

    for ($rdi->rewind();$rdi->valid();$rdi->next()) {

        if ($rdi->isDot())
            continue;

        if ($rdi->isDir() || $rdi->isFile()) {

            for ($i = 0; $i<=$depth;++$i)
                echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

            echo $rdi->current().'<br />';

            if ($rdi->hasChildren())
                getFiles($rdi->getChildren(),1+$depth);
        }
    }
}

$depth = 2;
getFiles(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.'), $depth);
?>
```